# gsub regex only match if beginning of string or has space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, gsub

I have a bunch of phrases with missing apostrophes, and I have an array of fixes like so:

```rb
phrase = "i d let some"

def contractions_to_fix
  [
    { missing: "let s", fixed: "let's" }, 
    { missing: "i d", fixed: "i'd" }
  ]
end
```

I'm trying to loop through the array of contractions to replace them, like this:

```rb
contractions_to_fix.each do |contraction|
  if phrase.include? contraction[:missing]
    idea_title.gsub! contraction[:missing], contraction[:fixed]
  end
end
```

The goal, for this example, would be to return `"i'd let some"`; however, every regex I've tried so far returns an incorrect response.

For example:

- `contraction[:missing]` results in `"i'd let'some`
- `/\bcontraction[:missing]\b/` results in `"i d let some"`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `contraction[:missing]` does not evaluate to a regular expression, but to a String.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to code the exact requirement in your title is to flip your condition around: "isn't preceded or followed by a non-space":

```
idea_title.gsub!(/(?<!\S)#{Regexp.escape(contraction[:missing])}(?!\S)/, contraction[:fixed])
```

Though `/\b#{...}\b/` should work for the example you gave. Your problem is likely the fact that you feed a `String` as the pattern into `gsub!` instead of `Regexp`, so you are literally looking for `\b` (backslash and lowercase `B`), not a word boundary. Try it with

```
idea_title.gsub!(/\b#{Regexp.escape(contraction[:missing])}\b/, contraction[:fixed])
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! If anyone has any additional suggestions, I'm still all ears, but very happy to have at least one solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
  { missing: "let s", fixed: "let's" }, 
  { missing: "i d", fixed: "i'd" }
]
```

```
h = arr.reduce({}) { |h,g| h.merge(g[:missing]=>g[:fixed]) }
  #=> {"let s"=>"let's", "i d"=>"i'd"}

r = /\b(?:#{h.keys.join('|')})\b/
  #=> /\b(?:let s|i d)\b/

"i d want to let some".gsub(r, h)
  #=> "i'd want to let some"
```

This uses the (second) form of [String.gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a hash as a second argument and has no block.

One may alternatively calculate `h` as follows.

```
h = arr.map { |g| g.values_at(:missing, :fixed) }.to_h
  #=> {"let s"=>"let's", "i d"=>"i'd"}
```